# Performance issue - DataTemplate and DataBinding - 1st load

Tags: wpf, performance, data-binding, datatemplate

Here a drawing of my UI:
[image]

I have a list of elements at the top (clickme1 and clickme2). Each of this element will have several information contained inside MyList that I want to display inside the customElement of the listbox.

Clickme1 is clicked by default. When I click on the Clickme2, the listbox is taking 2-3 seconds before updating the CustomElements by the information of the Clickme2. When I switch again, it's updating right away so the problem is visible only for the first click. CustomElement has a lot of different bindings to the Clickme element (images and texts).

Here my code:

```
public ObservableCollection<CustomClass> MyList { get; set; }


<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <local:CustomElement x:Name="MyCustomElement"/>
                </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Black">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

I tried to use the VirtualizingStackPanel instead of the WrapPanel but it did not improve anything.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

When you repopulate the collection, are you assigning a new ObservableCollection? Or working on the existing one?

You should populate your collection "off-line" and then bind it. Or Google for an ObservableCollection derivative that supports "bulk insert". The standard ObservableCollection will send a UI update for every insert.

WRONG:

```
MyList.Clear();
MyList.Add(...);
```

RIGHT:

```
ObservableCollection<CustomClass> coll = new ...
coll.Add(...);
MyList = coll;
```

Comment: I'm not repopulating the collection when the update is done. I'm binding my whole thing to a "currentClickme". So when I click on Clickme2, I'm calling a command that does "currentClickme = Clickme2".
Clickme1 and Clickme2 have an instance of MyList both of them.